# Can I set a revision tag for my google cloud run service via terraform?

Tags: terraform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, knative

I'd like to set a [revision tag](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#tags) on the cloud run service revision created by applying my terraform plan.

I see nothing in the [terraform cloud run service documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#argument-reference) that would allow me to set a revision tag.  I tried the following, for the heck of it:

```
traffic {
  percent = 100
  tag     = my-tag
}
```

which results in an Unsupported Argument Error.

I've explored the alternative strategy of using `gcloud` commands to add the tag after the revision is created; however, any commands which successfully tag the latest revision also remove tags from any prior revisions (I suppose because I'm updating the `service` wholesale, rather that modifying a particular `revision`).

Comment: It seems not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue. After hunting on the [hashcorp github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues) issues, I realized that the fix was just recently included, so you need to update your google provider.

Here a working configuration that has supported `tag` inside `traffic` module:

```
terraform {

    required_providers {
        google = {
          source  = "hashicorp/google"
          version = "~> 4.52.0"
        }
      }

    required_version = ">= 1.1.9"
}
```